# Is there a way to apply css style to a disabled ion-select-option

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a list of statuses , i want the user to select one , not all statuses are enabled some of them will be disabled .
I want the disabled options to have some css styling (like gray color)

```
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
      <ion-select-option [disabled]="isStatusDisabled(o)" *ngFor="let o of appointmentStatusOptions" [value]="o">
        {{appointmentStatus[o]}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
```

i have tired to select the element by :disabled like:

```
ion-select-option[disabled] {
--color:gray;
}
```

and tried to change all disabled as disperate action like :

```
:disabled {
--color:gray;
}
```

the css style doesn't appear at the borwser at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ionic adds class `.select-disabled` for the `disabled` select so you can try to specify that in your css

Answer (score 1):

To change globally you can add this in component style sheet:

```
::shadow /deep/ button[disabled] .alert-radio-label {
  color: gray;
}
```

Or on `global.scss`:

```
ion-alert button[disabled] .alert-radio-label {
  color: gray;
  // color: var(--ion-color-gray, gray);
}
```